# jQuery Get the length of a specific list among multiple lists

Tags: jquery

I have multiple  elements as siblings.

How would I get the length of, say, the 2nd  in jQuery?

I've tried

```
$("#secondary_menu ul")[1].find("li").length()
```

and

```
$("#secondary_menu ul").get(1).find("li").size()
```

but no dice.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.eq()`.

`.get()` and the bracket notation are used to access the DOM objects from a jQuery object:

```
 $("#secondary_menu ul").eq(1).find("li").length
```

Comment: Almost correct. Thank you! The parentheses at the end must be omitted.

Comment: @widerheim: Sorry, I didn't read it carefully. You could use `size()` instead.